# MAX value of column with corresponding columns

Tags: sql-server-2000

I am using an old SQL Server 2000.

Here is some sample data:

```
ROOMDATE                rate    bus_id  quantity
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000  129    346686  2
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000  162    354247  36
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000  159    382897  150
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000  120    556111  25
2018-09-22 00:00:00.000  129    346686  8
2018-09-22 00:00:00.000  162    354247  86
2018-09-22 00:00:00.000  159    382897  150
2018-09-22 00:00:00.000  120    556111  25
2018-09-23 00:00:00.000  129    346686  23
2018-09-23 00:00:00.000  162    354247  146
2018-09-23 00:00:00.000  159    382897  9
2018-09-23 00:00:00.000  94     570135  23
```

Essentially what I am wanting is the MAX quantity of each day with it's corresponding rate and bus_id.

For example, I would want the following rows from my sample data above:

```
ROOMDATE                rate    bus_id  quantity
2018-09-21 00:00:00.000  159    382897  150
2018-09-22 00:00:00.000  159    382897  150
2018-09-23 00:00:00.000  162    354247  146
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read, SQL Server 2000 did not support `ROW_NUMBER`.  But we can phrase your query using a subquery which finds the max quantity for each day:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        CONVERT(char(10), ROOMDATE, 120) AS ROOMDATE,
        MAX(quantity) AS max_quantity
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY CONVERT(char(10), ROOMDATE, 120)
) t2
    ON CONVERT(char(10), t1.ROOMDATE, 120) = t2.ROOMDATE AND
       t1.quantity = t2.max_quantity
ORDER BY
    t1.ROOMDATE;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Sadly SQL Server 2000 does not have a ROW_NUMBER() function. I thought of doing that.

Comment: @zfemmer Reload your page.  I also realized this, and gave you an old school alternative.